# How to Override Capybara reset_sessions

Tags: cucumber, capybara

I saw that Capybara uses something called Capybara.reset_sessions! in its library under cucumber.rb like this

```
After do
 Capybara.reset_sessions!
end

Before '@javascript' do
  Capybara.current_driver = Capybara.javascript_driver
end

Before do |scenario|
  scenario.source_tag_names.each do |tag|
   driver_name = tag.sub(/^@/, '').to_sym
   if Capybara.drivers.has_key?(driver_name)
     Capybara.current_driver = driver_name
   end
  end
end

After do
 Capybara.use_default_driver
end
```

how can override this value Capybara.reset_sessions!..??

I don't want to reset_sessions after every time a scenario completes. can someone suggest me a way how to do it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and found the answer here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/ruby-capybara/vA4CH2kTVO8/XdiXEDgY2tMJ

Basically you don't `require 'capybara/cucumber'` and just require the individual files you need from capybara/cucumber.rb.

In my case I was using rspec instead of cucumber, so I omitted `require 'capybara/rspec'` and required the files I needed.